# Graphical components stuck on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, kde5, window-decoration

I have Kubuntu 16.04 with kde 5.6.5, and I cannot change the graphical components, I am stuck with the qtcurve style.

Here is a screenshot of the settings, as you can see, the style selected (and applied) is Fusion, but the qtcurve is still used.
[image]

I am using a laptop with intel graphics and nvidia card, and I had problems insalling drivers because of the optimus system.
While trying to reinstall my graphics drivers, I ended up installing the ubuntu desktop on my system (I don't remember the exact command).
On the login screen, I can now choose between plasma and Ubuntu.

I don't know if it's related, but I thought it was useful to mention it.

I tried rebooting, no luck.

This is not an urgent problem (qtcurve style is good), but this is annoying and I like having a working system :D

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you using Unity with KDE?

Comment: I never used Unity with KDE, but I think I installed it by mistake, because I can choose ubuntu in the log in screen

Comment: Installation is enough to override settings. You can't really use Unity with KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cause of the Problem

I experienced this same problem yesterday and discovered that, some packages was overriding QT style with gtk looks. The environment variables in question were `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` and `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME`.

### Solution

The solution is putting these lines in `~/.profile` file to unset the environment variables.

```
## Fixing QT style override problem
if [ "x$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP" == "xKDE" ] || [ "x$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP" == "xplasma" ];
then
    unset QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE
    unset QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
fi
```

Now, the style should be changeable and will persist.

Comment: well doing echo $QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE returns nothing, just a blank line

Comment: what is the output of `env | grep QT`? @Keplyx

Comment: QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
QT_IM_MODULE=compose

Comment: Aha! found it. I've updated the answer. @Keplyx check it now

Comment: Still not working, but I think I know why. I'm dumb and said I was stuck with qtcurve, but this is wrong, I'm stuck with Style GTK+. This is because I had this problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/812270/color-problem-on-kubuntu-16-04. So I changed the GTK2 theme to oxygen-gtk. Still don't know how to fix this tho

Comment: @Keplyx you added that to ~/.bashrc and logout and login? I too reproduced this problem and it solved that way

Comment: Yes, I added the lines in the .bashrc file in home directory (at the end of the file) but as I said, I'm stuck with gtk+ theme, not qtcurve, my mistake :/

Comment: What is the output of `env | grep QT` now?

Comment: QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
QT_IM_MODULE=compose

Comment: @Keplyx if that doesn't work, add those lines in `~/.profile` file. `.bashrc` might been ignored. I see a similar case now.